# On using Elisp macros for partial application

Tags: elisp-macros

I want to improve my Elisp, but despite reading about the differences between functions and macros (including discussions [here in Emacs SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21015/when-to-use-macro-or-not-to-use) and [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6w45aj/what_is_the_use_case_for_elisp_macros/)), I still find examples where the distinction confuses me.

For example, in the "starter-pack" Radian, a [macro can be found](https://github.com/raxod502/radian/blob/develop/emacs/radian.el#L325) which wraps `use-package` ensuring some sort of partial application:

```el
(defmacro use-feature (name &rest args)
  "Like `use-package', but with `straight-use-package-by-default' disabled."
  (declare (indent defun))
  `(use-package ,name
     :straight nil
     ,@args))
```

As a case study, would it not be possible to achieve the same with a `defun`? After all, this seems like a simple case of partial application, or am I missing something? Do we need a macro here just because `use-package` itself is a macro which we don't want a `defun` body to evaluate?

And would there be a safe way to improve this macro to take care of a possibly unwanted case `(use-feature foo :straight t)`?

Comment: Macros can manage their raw arguments, while functions can't. If `use-package` is a functions, user will have to quote the arguments which is inconvenient and ugly, e.g., `(use-package 'foo :if '(<= 1 2) :commands #'foo-bar :bind '("C-c C-c" . foo))`, the same applies to `use-feature`, and if `use-feature` is not a macro, the use of it won't be like `use-package`.

Comment: What @xuchunyang said, where "raw" args means they are not evaluated when passed to the macro code.  A macro can do anything it likes with/to any arg it is passed, including ignore it or evaluate it. A macro produces *code*, which is then evaluated. A macro can do anything with its args, but it is *not* about partial application per se. Partial application is about function application to fewer than all of the function's args. If an arg to a macro is a function then it can apply it partially to some args. Otherwise, there is no connection between partial eval and macros.

Comment: As usual, a good way to learn about Elisp macros is to *ask Emacs*. `C-h i`, then choose `Emacs Lisp Intro`. In that intro-to-Elisp manual you'll find node [Lisp macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Lisp-macro.html), which will help. Or choose `Elisp`, the Emacs-Lisp reference and guide. There you'll find node [Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Macros.html), which fills you in about Elisp macros. Much better than getting ad hoc answers here or on Reddit (IMHO). You're not the first person to learn Lisp macros - trust Emacs to help.

Comment: At least one of these comments deserves to be promoted to an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but every question deserves an answer. You basically had it with "because use-package itself is a macro which we don't want a defun body to evaluate". More specifically, it couldn't be a defun, because:

1. Order Of Evaluation: `use-package` defines the order of evaluation (before and after loading its package) with, for example, the `:init`, `:config` and `:after` keywords. If `use-feature` were a defun, all arguments would be evaluated in order.
2. Quoting: Some `use-package` sections, such as `:bind` take unquoted data as arguments (which would throw an error for not being a function), and many take an unquoted symbols (which emacs would try to evaluate as variables). You could require the user to manually quote everything, but that would make the `use-feature` API very different from `use-package`.

To answer the finall question at the end of the post - if there are 2 `:straight` keywords, the order of evaluation depends on the internals of `use-package`. If this version of the macro lets the user override it, swapping the lines `,@args` and `:straight t` would probably change that behaviour. But might not, and you probably can't know without reading the code of `use-package`.